# How to read multiple files in a directory by matching a pattern in perl?

Tags: perl

How to read multiple files in a directory by matching a pattern?

I have a directory containing a few directories. Each directory contains a '.log' file and a directory named Cov_work. Each log file in the directory either has a "Pass" string or a "Fail" string. I need to separate both and store the .log with the pass string in a new directory along with the Cov_work. I am able to transfer the files but not the directory. I apologize for my first post as it was a little jumbled all together. The program is given below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy::Recursive qw(fcopy rcopy dircopy fmove rmove dirmove);

my $dir  = ("/home/Narayanan/Cov_script/logs");
my $home  = ("/home/Narayanan/Cov_script");
my $dest_dir = "Pass_dir";
my $dest_dir1 = ("/home/Narayanan/Cov_script/Pass_dir/");


   if (-e $dest_dir) {
        print "$dest_dir already exists\n";
   } else {
    system("mkdir $dest_dir");
   }

my @file =   `grep "TEST HAS PASSED" $dir/*/*.log`;

my $cov = "Cov_work";

print "@file\n";

my $i=0;


    foreach my $cnt(@file){

           my $pf_names  = (split(/ /, $file[$i])) [-3];
       my $pf_names1 = (split(/:/, $pf_names)) [-2];

       my $cov_names  = $pf_names1;
       my @cov_names1 = split /\//, $cov_names;

       pop @cov_names1;
       my $cov_new2 = $cov_names1[-1];
       print ("1 : Last Element $cov_new2\n"); 

       $cov_names = join('/', @cov_names1);
       my $cov_names2 = ("$cov_names/$cov");

       if (-e $dest_dir1){

        system (chdir "$dest_dir1");
        system (mkdir "$cov_new2");
        system (chdir "$home");
       }
       else {
        print "Can't create the directory\n";
       }

       my $pass_path = ("$dest_dir1$cov_new2");
       print " Moved Location : $pass_path\n";

       print " Cov : $cov_names\n";

       if (-e $pf_names1){

        print "$pf_names1\n";
        fcopy ($pf_names1, $pass_path);
        }
       else { 
        print "No path found\n";
    }

       if (-e $cov_names){

        print "Inside Cover loop: $cov_names2\n";
        dircopy ($cov_names2, $pass_path) or die "Can't copy";
        }
       else { 
        print "No cover report found\n";
    }

   $i++;
     }

print "$i\n";
$i=0;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Right now your question does not clearly say what you want to do. Is the `Pass`/`Fail` in the file's name or the file's content? Please [edit] your question and clarify. Please also add the code you have already written.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question as is - you haven't given us enough detail. It _sounds_ pretty straightforward, but an example of e.g. filenames, etc. and perhaps some code that you've tried already would help us understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome at stackoverflow!

To give you a concret and helpful solution to your problem you have to specify your problem as eaxactly as you can.
Out of your decription I get the following Information:

- Your script operates with files
- you want to copy some files from directory a/ to directory b/
- you are able to open each file and read it
- you want to check whether each file contains the String `Pass` or `Fail`
- you don't have any problems with copying the files

To solve your exact problem we would need to know:

- How are these files structured
- how do you read in each file?
- does the String has to appear at the end of a line, middle, begin?

Nevertheless I'll give it a shot. I assume that you read the files **line by line** and that you can process each line seperately.
Then you can use a `regex` to check the occurence of your certain strings.

```
... you read the file line by line and store
... temporary each line in the variable $line...
... for each line you check:
chomp($line);
if( $line =~ /^Pass$/ ){
  #the line begins immediatly with the string 'Pass' and after that the line
  #the line terminates
}
if( $line =~ /Pass/){
  #somewhere in the $line the String 'Pass' occurs
}
if( $line =~ /^Pass/){
  #the line starts with the String 'Pass'
}
if( $line =~ /Pass$/){
  #the line terminates with the String 'Pass'
}
```

The same thing is possible with the String `Fail` of course.

Comment: I know you're trying to help, but I'm really not convinced this is particularly useful - the OP's detail is vague, so your answer in return must necessarily be so. This in turn makes it unlikely to be much help to people who refer to Stack Overflow in future, and may well not help the OP much either.

Comment: Well you may be correct in your assumption to say that it won't be that much useful for other people browsing stackoverflow. But there are many many highly specific questions which aren't also. From my point of view, I say that stackoverflow is a place to help from programmer to programmer. And in fact my post answers his question about the string-checking. I can partially agree with you and so I think it's a greyish environment we're discussion about.